# Open Youtube Video With Image on iPhone Safari HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, iframe, youtube

Could someone please help me to figure out how to use a placeholder image to open a youtube video on mobile so that if the user clicks the image on the html page in safari on iphone, the video automatically plays fullscreen (note: on iphone the video would automatically go fullscreen in this instance, just as when you click an embedded youtube iframe).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does the normal syntax below give you some sort of issue? It looks ok on my emulator... :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ALqFFeU-Wp8">Full Screen</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This opens a url, and even using target=blank it would still be opening a url. When you click an iframe youtube video on iphone the video becomes fullscreen and autplays. I'm looking to have the same thing occur but using an image or text.